# UNIX Terminal: Replace text inside of a printed string without clearing the rest of the line

Tags: terminal, posix, ansi-escape

1. I have written "Hello world" to the standard output.
2. I print the `ESC[{y};{x}f` to put the cursor where the letter `w` is.
3. I print `b`.

What I get is `Hello b`.
I'd like to get a `Hello borld`, or at least `Hello bworld`(`Hello wborld` would also work).

I've tried using all of the escape codes that are related to the cursor position, but to no avail -- the line following the text printed in step 3 is cleared.